# Java: ArrayList of "Transaction" Objects: adding specific values

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm stuck on this implementation so please help me out.
I have an Object "Transaction" and Date:

```
public Transaction(double value, Date date){
     this.value = value;
     this.date = date;
}

public Date(int day, int month, int year){
     this.day = day;
     this.month = month;
     this.year = year;
}
```

Now in my main program, I have an ArrayList of :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    ArrayList <Transaction> cost = new ArrayList <Transaction(){{
          add(new Transaction(11.52, new Date(7,12, 1999));
          add(new Transaction(52.87, new Date(3,7, 1999));
          add(new Transaction(5.22, new Date(5, 7, 1999));
    }};
}
```

Now my question is, I want to generate a Monthly graph of the transaction. But There are 2 Nodes in my month of "7". How would I add the values in the month "7" in order to produce 1 Node? So in my case, I would have to add 52.87 + 5.22 because they're both in the month "7".

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Just create a method Transaction.combine(Transaction t). But which date would the new node have?

Comment: I don't want it to store it in the new Node. I just want to temporarily output as 1 value for that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create getters for Date and Transaction and then do the following:

```
double [] months = new double[12];
for (Transaction t : cost) {
    months[t.getDate().getMonth() - 1] += t.getCost();
}
```

After you will have the sum of all values for each month in the `months` array, where the indices are the months of the year starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to create only one node for a given month

```
   add(new Transaction(5.22+52.87, new Date(5, 7, 1999));
```

I would recommend using calendar class as above is deprecated as above date constructor is deprecated